# I am not being able to show array list in list view in android

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-studio, arraylist

I am getting the value from my parse db in list view. But the problem is I am not being able to structured the output.
e.g
When i calling the parse class i am getting output as
[image]

Whereas i need something like

john

1A Camac Street

123456789

john@testmail.com

All as one list item then another name and details and so on.

I am using code:

```
ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Stage1");
 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException error) {
                if (error == null) {

                    ArrayList<String> arraystage = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (ParseObject j : objects) {

                        arraystage.add(j.getString("Name"));
                        arraystage.add(j.getString("Address"));
                        arraystage.add(j.getString("Phone"));
                        arraystage.add(j.getString("Email"));
                        //arraystage.subList(1,4);
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Userprofile_view.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraystage);
                    lvdet.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        });
```

So any one can help me.

Comment: You should read about custom adapters for `ListView`. In particular, Parse provides an implementation that works seamlessly with Parse.

Answer (score 1):

By default `ArrayAdapter` uses item's `toString()` to get the item text.

If you need something else you have to override `ArrayAdapter.getView()`

Comment: >In your case `arraystage.toString()`.............That doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1):

For such a list, you can't use `simple_list_item`. You need to create a custom view and override the `getView` method. Checkout this post http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-adapter-and.html

I also think it would make thing easier if you use an `Contact` object that you populate with data from parse object

```
class Contact{
   String name, address, phone, email;
}
```

And the adapter

```
    ArrayList<Contact> arraystage = new ArrayList<Contact>();

                for (ParseObject j : objects) {

                       Contact c = new Contact();

                       c.name = j.getString("Name");
                       c.address = j.getString("Address");
                       c.phone = j.getString("Phone");
                       c.email = j.getString("Email");
                       arraystage.add(c);
                 }

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Userprofile_view.this, android.R.layout.your_custom_view, arraystage){
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        }
   };

lvdet.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that depends on the view hierarchy of the custom view

Comment: I deleted my comment because I was confused with `SimpleCursorAdapter` which has a constructor where you can provide the mapping from columns to view ids in the row.

Comment: Would  `class Contact extends ParseObject` complicate your answer too much?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Again it depends. If it's documented to be extensible then it wouldn't complicate things